# Powershell spilt and manipulate data

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a semi small csv file which is around 3000 rows. Below is a example of what the data looks like in the CSV.  I want to rearrange the CSV using powershell (split), instead of creating pivot tables to manipulate the data

```
   DS12345;Group 1, Group 2, Group 3, Group 4
   DB09876;Group 1, Group 2, Group 3
   AB01020;Group 9, Group 8
```

I would like to scan the original CSV then create a new CSV file perhaps on my desktop with the data looking like this below, groups(second column) on one line with the identifier (first column).  The data will be sorted already in the CSV.

```
   DS12345;Group 1
   DS12345;Group 2
   DS12345;Group 3
   DS12345;Group 4
   BD09876;Group 1
   BD09876;Group 2
   BD09876;Group 3
   AB01020;Group 9
   AB01020;Group 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a couple of splits to chop up each line, something like this:

```
Get-Content InputFile.csv | % {
    $a = $_ -split ';'
    $a[1] -split ',\s*' | % {
        "$($a[0]);$($_)"
    }
} | Set-Content OutputFile.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

Almost does the trick.  With the above code its only assigns the first variable if multiple groups are assigned

eg

```
     DS12345;Group 1, Group 2, Group 3, Group 4
```

will be

```
     DS12345;Group 1
```

not as im hoping

```
    DS12345;Group 1
    DS12345;Group 2
    DS12345;Group 3
    DS12345;Group 4
```